# Laravel - homestead.rb cannot be loaded

Tags: php, ruby, laravel, vagrantfile

I used the homestead executable to install homestead in one of my laravel projects., when i vagrant up, i get the following error message;

> > There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by a syntax
> >     error.
>
> Path: /Users/tommorison/Code/CSToss/Vagrantfile Line number: 12
>   Message: LoadError: cannot load such file --
>   /Users/tommorison/Code/CSToss/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb

Here is my vagrantfile

> require 'json' require 'yaml'
>
> VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2" confDir = $confDir ||=
>   File.expand_path("vendor/laravel/homestead", File.dirname(**FILE**))
>
> homesteadYamlPath = "Homestead.yaml" homesteadJsonPath =
>   "Homestead.json" afterScriptPath = "after.sh" aliasesPath = "aliases"
>
> require File.expand_path(confDir + '/scripts/homestead.rb')
>
> Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
>       if File.exists? aliasesPath then
>           config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
>       end
>
> ```
> if File.exists? homesteadYamlPath then
>     Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))
> elsif File.exists? homesteadJsonPath then
>     Homestead.configure(config, JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath)))
> end
>
> if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
>     config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
> end end
> ```

Why am I getting this message? all the docs i've read pertain to homestead 2.0. i'm using 3,0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.